# HTML email side by side images 1-2px too wide per image

Tags: html-email, electronic-direct-mail

Having trouble with emails that have multiple images side by side but each row has a different amount of columns/images. I'm putting a table in each row so I don't have to use colspan as the images are all different widths. The more images in a row, the wider the row even though all rows have the same combined width of all their images.

See image example here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bPH2.jpg]

Example HTML (See JS fiddle as the code won't post correctly here for some reason):

```
<table id="Table_1_col" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="ffffff"
   style="background:#fff;display:block;table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse!important;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-spacing:0;border:0;mso-cellspacing:0;mso-padding-alt:0;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;width:600px;min-width:600px;max-width:600px;"
   valign="top">
<tbody>
<tr style="display:block;white-space:nowrap;">
    <td style="font-size:0;line-height:0;margin:0;padding:0;background:url(images/_TRAVEL-15_05.jpg);background-image:url(images/_TRAVEL-15_05.jpg);background-size:100% 100%;"
        valign="top" align="left"><a href="https://www.afterpay.com/en-AU/categories/travel" align="left"
                                     style="font-size:0;line-height:0;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;" target="_blank"><img src="images/_TRAVEL-15_05.jpg"
                                                                                                                              width="600" height="241" alt=""
                                                                                                                              style="float:left;width:600px;display:block;margin:0;outline:0;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:0;"
                                                                                                                              border="0" align="left"></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jup4xw3v/3/

The email has a set width of 600px and the additional side width is most notable on mobile devices where it breaks the flow of the email. The rows are weird widths due to the click areas from our designer.

No matter what I try I can't seem to get the rows displaying at the exact same width.

Comment: **Two things:** Your td's dont have any widths associated with them and as for your images, use the width as an attribute and not on the style. Outlook will display the images at its original size if you have only given width in the style.

Comment: @Syfer IMG tags have a width attribute & width style. Added the width attribute to TD's but it's still happening. Funnily enough they display fine in Outlook, it's only on mobile devices that I'm getting issues.